# Acidity of H4P2O7 and H3PO4

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

As given in [pK<sub>a</sub> of H<sub>4</sub>P<sub>2</sub>O<sub>7</sub> and H<sub>3</sub>PO<sub>4</sub>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrophosphoric_acid). The acidity of pyrophosphoric acid is clearly stronger than phosphoric acid. The two acid structures is given below.

**Thought**: Consider the pyrophosphoric acid dissociates first proton on the left, the stronger acidity might be attributed to the other phosphate group on the right. In other words, I think that the induction effect of the other P=O group results to O-H bond more polarized compared to H<sub>3</sub>PO<sub>4</sub>

Is it true in this case?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you checked whether the effect is not simply *statistical*? One molecule has 4 x OH, the other 3 x OH (correction!) that can dissociate. That alone can explain why one has a higher acidity. To figure out if that is the case, assume you were determining the pKa of a substance but were mistakenly using 4/3 x  the concentration that you thought you were. How would this affect the pKa determination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your thought process is on the right track.

**Reason**: The enhanced acidity of pyrophosphoric acid (H₄P₂O7) compared to phosphoric acid (H₃PO₄) can be attributed to the presence of the additional phosphate group. The induction effect of the adjacent **P=O** group in pyrophosphoric acid makes the **O-H** bond more polarized, making it easier for the molecule to donate a proton, thereby increasing its acidity. This effect is a result of the electron-withdrawing nature of the phosphate group, which strengthens the acidity of the compound.